# Lining up columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have a set of disorganized data in Excel where I need to line up columns with the same header.

For example I have data that looks like this

```
! SoftwareX v2.49
Header A   Header B   Header C   Header D
1          blue       Monday     11:45AM 
2          red        Thursday   12:10 PM
! SoftwareX v2.49
Header A   Header C   Header D 
4          Saturday   4:20 AM 
8          Saturday   4:40 PM
```

The rows continue on in this fashion for quite a while, but column B will not always be present - and I don't care about column B. I would just like to line up column C like so (on a larger scale)

```
! SoftwareX v2.49
Header A   Header B   Header C   Header D
1          blue       Monday     11:45AM 
2          red        Thursday   12:10 PM
! SoftwareX v2.49
Header A              Header C   Header D 
4                     Saturday   4:20 AM 
8                     Saturday   4:40 PM
```

Thanks!

Comment: Organize the data before you import it into Excel

Answer (score 0):

I assume the order of the rows is important so start by inserting a column to the left of your messy data and filling it with numbers 1, 2, 3, etc.  My solution involves sorting the data, so you're going to use this new row to sort the data back to its original order afterwards.

Sort by the third column of your original data (the one which sometimes has Header C and sometimes D).  All the rows with a time will be bunched together, so go there and insert your blank "Header B" cells as appropriate.

This should hardly take a minute :)

Comment: It wasn't tagged as a programming problem

Comment: If this is a programming question, it's a "please write it for me" question and should be removed :(